# How to merge three old commits in pushed repository?

Tags: git

I have a repository on which three people work.
The repository was pushed to the server and works on production. We have only master branch.

If I use `git log`, then I have something like that:

```
commit 9999999 Author: A
commit 8888888 Author: B
commit 7777777 Author: A
commit 6666666 Author: C
commit 5555555 Author: B
commit 4444444 Author: A
commit 3333333 Author: A
commit 2222222 Author: C
```

But I would like have:

```
commit 9999999 Author: A
commit 8888888 Author: B
commit 7777777 Author: A
commit 6666666 Author: C
commit 5555555 Author: B // or other commit name
commit 2222222 Author: C
```

So I would like to merge 3333333, 4444444 and 5555555 to 5555555.

Is it possible if everyone has downloaded these changes and the application works on production?

Comment: Given that your `master` branch has been pushed, is public, and is shared, you can't/shouldn't rewrite the history of that branch.  Rewriting history is what would be needed to do what you want.  But, moving forward, you may do things like squash local commits, consolidate, etc., _before_ you push to the remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before I get started, what Tim Biegeleisen wrote in the comments above is correct.  If you re-write history on the server, this means that all collaborators will be out-of-sync, and will probably need a fresh clone of the repo.  You also might not have permissions to re-write history on the server.

That out of the way, if I understand correctly, you're looking to combine commits `4444444`, `3333333` and `2222222` into just `2222222`.  In that case you're looking to do a `rebase`.

I recommend cloning your repo to another directory to use as a sandbox (`cd ~/my_sandbox; git clone ~/my/repo/location)`.  This is a safety measure.  If you muck up at any time during the rebase process you can type `git rebase --abort`, and you should be back where you started (with all commits).

If you wish to combine the most *recent 3* commits, type:
`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Then you'll be presented with an interactive screen in a text editor.

```
pick 4444444 Commit message #4
pick 3333333 Commit message #3
pick 2222222 Commit message #2
```

Squash all three into one like so:

```
pick 4444444 Commit message #4
s 3333333 Commit message #3
s 2222222 Commit message #2
```

Save and exit the text editor.
Then you'll be given another screen where you can create a brand new commit message:

```
[ Squashed commit ]
 - This is a squashed commit of my most recent 3 commits.
```

Note: Every line beginning with a `#` will be ignored and not included in your new commit message.  Save and exit text editor.

Type `git log` to see the new look.  The *3 latest* commits will be squashed into one.  But keep in mind, that will have a *new commit hash*, it will not be `2222222`.  If you want to check your work, you can type `git show` to show all changes in the squashed commit.

Comment: Thanks! Now every collaborator and production will be able to safely pull the changes and will have the same 'git log' as me?

Comment: Yes, but they will need to do a fresh clone of the repo off the server, once you have finished your work.  Remember to practice in a sandbox until you're satisfied before you push to the server.